# Amazon Product Advertising API "The ItemId is not accessible through the Product Advertising API" but the product is still on the site

Tags: amazon-product-api, paapi

I am writing a wordpress plugin to check the availability of Amazon products.
I mostly do this through the use of their Product Advertising API (PAAPI5).

I know that the API not returning any offers for an ASIN means that the product is currently unavailable, but I have come across cases where the API has returned an `ItemNotAccessible` error code even though the product does exist on Amazon, is in stock, and isn't discontinued by the manufacturer.

An example is for ASIN `B00081UPLK`

```
'errors': [{'code': 'ItemNotAccessible',
             'message': 'The ItemId B00081UPLK is not accessible through the '
                        'Product Advertising API.'}
```

Do I need to use a different API?